# How to access the n-th related channel entry (EE 2.6.1 relationships)

Tags: relationships

If I have (as in the ee 2.6.1 docs) a channel ParentChannel, with a field relationship_field, relating to multiple ChildChannel entries, how do I find the total number of related ChildChanel entries for a given ParentChanel entry, and how do I access just the n-th ChildChanel entry (without having to loop through all of them)?